# NodeJS proxy with REST and parameters

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, proxy, axios, node-modules

To have a NodeJS server acting as a gateway to a private server.  A simple REST endpoint is working as follows.  However I am seeking a solution that will also pass through whatever parameters Axios might send.

**Axios Call to proxy server Example**

```js
   return axios
      .post(http://proxy.server + "/company/add_company", { address:"123 main", phone:"555-1234" })
```

**Proxy Server**

```js
const caller = async (response, rest, params) => {
    try {

        params = JSON.parse(params);
        const result = await axios.post('http://10.0.0.0'+ rest, { params } );

        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            result: result.data
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            err
        })
    }
}

app.all("/", (request, response) => {

     let params = request.body // <= not working
     let rest = request.url;  //  <= working example =>  /users/235
     caller(response, rest, params);

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me.

```js
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
 
const app = express();

app.use('/', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://10.0.0.0' , changeOrigin: true }));
app.listen(5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parser middleware to receive post data from client, the data will be stored in request.body.
Example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(express.json())
```